# Session example doesn't work

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to learn about using sessions.

saw the following code example on a tutorial:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $_SESSION['username'] = "hello";

    echo $_SESSION['username'];
?>
```

I do get `hello` when I execute the page, however, according to that tutorial, I should keep getting `hello` from now on (until closing the browser), with this code:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    echo $_SESSION['username'];
?>
```

But I don't. what's wrong?

***EDIT*:**

According to your comments, I've updated my code to look like this:

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
session_start();
session_name("untitled");
$_SESSION['username'] = "hello";
echo $_SESSION['username'];
echo session_id();
?>
```

I'm getting two no headers sent error:

`Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by..... on line 3`

`Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent by..... on line 3`

I've looked at the general thread that deals with this error, but in my case I can't figure what's wrong with these simple lines of code.

***EDIT2***

If I switch between line 2 and 3 as follows, I no longer get the headers sent error on one of my servers. on another domain and server, I keep getting it. anyway, the `session_id` keeps on changing on every refresh on both servers and codes.

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(-1);
session_name("untitled");
$_SESSION['username'] = "hello";
echo $_SESSION['username'];
echo session_id();
?>
```

Comment: by doing what, changing the code of your same file, or in another file? Use a conditional statement to check if the session is set/not empty. use error reporting also http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: You could also check if sessions are enabled on the webserver with the phpinfo() function: http://it2.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

Comment: @Mat OP: *"I do get `hello` when I execute the page*. That shows that sessions are enabled.

Comment: my first comment is 4 minutes old. My span of attention these days is 5 on first comments. @ me if you need me when I close this tab in 1 minute. *Time is a precious commodity*.

Comment: check `session_id()` in both scripts. if that changes, then something is causing your sessions to get "lost". bad cookie settings being the usual culprit.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I tried both changing same file into the second code, as well as using the second code in a new file. both failed. shouldn't both methods yield same result though? does it matter?

Comment: `if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && !empty($_SESSION['username'])){ echo $_SESSION['username']; } else { echo "Session died"; }` in all files using sessions. Again; error reporting.

Comment: Is there any output before your session_start() - even a whitespace corrupts your session. Check if error reporting is on (hard way: "include('non_existant.php');" )

Comment: if it's a whitespace issue, or bom etc. then error reporting will throw a notice.

Comment: @MarcB you're onto it I guess. My session ID changes each time I refresh the page. why is it so?

Comment: *"My session ID changes each time I refresh the page."* this tells me you're not showing us the whole picture.

Comment: yeah, but only if error reporting (and display_errors - who checks log files) is on. @rockyraw Check if there is a "PHPSESSID" cookie in your browser

Comment: @rockyraw: you could try to set the session name: `session_name("WebsiteID");` - ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php

Comment: @clemens321  what's the easiest way to check for that cookie? I don't think I see it.

Comment: @Mat adding that line to the code doesn't make a difference, session ID still keep changing...

Comment: Depends on your browser. In firefox it is menu settings, privacy, show cookies (or using firebug or another developer extension if you installed it). For other browsers please google, should be easy to find

Comment: @rockyraw: session_name is before session_start? About the cookie... you could also try with different browsers to see if it depends on some unusual setting

Comment: @Mat there's no difference if before or after. error occuring on 3 different browsers. I've tested the same code on another server, and over there I'm getting a "headers already sent" error along with the output. any clue yet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: [First comment...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33814449/session-example-doesnt-work#comment55394451_33814449) told you what to do and to have told us about that "notice" from the get-go. [Then this 2nd comment...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33814449/session-example-doesnt-work#comment55394823_33814449) said about a notice. But you didn't share that *"headers already sent"*. You've had us all going from the start. I'd of answered this a mere "minute" after you posting your question. Do you think I put links in comments "just cuz"?

Comment: @Fred-ii- The "headers sent" error appears only on another server I tested it on. I discovered it only after those comments. I have no clue what does it indicate if on the first server this error doesn't show up.

Comment: consult the link that was included above http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Comment: @Fred-ii- I've edited my thread. looked in that link, but in my specific code I can't figure what's wrong exactly.

Comment: Edited again, I don't think the headers sent is really the issue here, I overcome it on my of my servers.

Comment: @clemens321 I didn't find such cookie in any of my browsers. but actually, a cookie with that name was not found for none of the domains I have visited during the past months.

Comment: I opened a new updated [thread here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33825348/session-id-changing-on-refresh-session-cookie-doesnt-show-up-in-browser)