# Session_ID keeps changing on refresh; Cookie isn't being sent to browser

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies

I've went through various threads about this problem and couldn't find a solution.

I'm using the following code:

```
<?php
session_start();
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
error_reporting(-1);
session_name("hello");
$_SESSION['username'] = "name";
echo $_SESSION['username'];
echo session_id();
if (is_writable(session_save_path()))
{
    echo "writable";
}
?>
```

This is the output:

`name771e6d83a8578e2dbadac64dc62b5788writable`

Yet the session ID output **keeps changing on every page refresh**.

It is happening in all browsers I tried (Chrome, IE, FF).

In none of the browsers I couldn't locate a `PHPSESSID` cookie that is supposed to be sent from my domain.

Since the output yields `writable`, this shouldn't be a permission problem.

These are my `php.ini` settings:

[image]

`session_auto_start` is set to `0`, like I guess it should be.

What can be causing this problem?

I'm trying to learn sessions, started with this simple code and can't get over this issue.

**Another note:** 
As you can see, I've set error reporting, and I don't get any special errors when I test this code on my VPS server.
However, when I run the same code on some shared hosting account that I have on another server, I'm getting a `headers already sent on line 2` error. I don't what exactly is making the difference, but I intend to run my project only on my VPS server anyway.

Comment: Locate and fix the `headers already sent` error. Even if there is no error message displayed on the other server, the error itself might still be present, and prevent the script from properly setting the session id cookie.

Comment: @CBroe I'm a newbie and really have no clue what might be causing this error. I've read a thread about that error, but couldn't tell. I posted the whole code here, so where else can this come from?

Comment: That error has been broadly discussed already. And the error message already tells you where the first output was generated.

Comment: @CBroe It might have been discussed buy I couldn't figure what is it that I should do from that discussion. I don't understand the error message - where are headers sent first time and when are they being sent second time in my code? how to control that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8028987/1427878 should tell you all you need to know.

Comment: @CBroe Already looked at it before posting the thread, that's a long list and I couldn't figure out what is relevant. besides, that list doesn't really offer a solution, it just says what might be causing this. I need a way to fix the above 5 lines of code.